# Hydroponic dataset

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, releasing-data

I have the intention of performing a machine learning project on hydroponic culture. The real problem is that it seems that there is not a public dataset available for this purpose.

I'm particularly interested in predicting the results of culture ( such as size of the fruits, size of the plant, etc..) in relation to the temperature, macronutrients, etc.. .

Could you please suggest me any method to find a dataset?